# Is there a short way to prove that $(\mathcal{P}(X),\Delta)$ is a commutative group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, infinite-groups

Is there a way to prove that $(\mathcal{P}(X),\Delta)$ is a commutative group, where $\Delta$ denotes the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), without doing tedious computations?

Comment: One interesting observation; After showing it is abelian group, you can easiliy see that every nontrivial elements oreder is $2$ since $A\Delta A= \phi$ then it is isomorphic to $Z_2xZ_2..$.Thus it has $2^k$ elements...(we already know this but it is kind of group theorical proof)

Answer (score 2):

Define for $A\in\mathcal P(X)$ the characteristic function $\chi_A $ on $X$ by
$$\chi(x)=1\;\text{if}\; x\in A\;\text{and $0$ otherwise}$$
and prove that
$$\chi_A\chi_B=\chi_{A\cap B}$$
$$\chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_{A\cap B}=\chi_{A\cup B}$$
$$\chi_{A^c}=1-\chi_A$$
and use this function to answer your question.

Comment: $\chi_A+\chi_B=\chi_{A\cup B}$ only if $1+1=1$. Maybe you want $1+1=0$ (as in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) and have $\chi_A+\chi_B = \chi_{A\Delta B}$?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To continue the thought I made in a comment on Sami Ben Romdhanes answer, first prove that $\mathbb Z_2$ is a additive group. Then consider the set
$$
\operatorname{Maps}(X,\mathbb Z_2)=\left\{\, f\colon X\to\mathbb Z_2\, \right\}
$$
of maps from $X$ to $\mathbb Z_2$. This is again a commutative group with pointwise addition. Now consider the map
\begin{align}
\chi : \mathcal P(X) &\longrightarrow \operatorname{Maps}(X,\mathbb Z_2) \\
A &\longmapsto \chi_A
\end{align}
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A\subseteq X$. This map is a bijection and we have
$$
\chi_{A\Delta B} = \chi_A + \chi_B,
$$
thus $(\mathcal P(X),\Delta)$ and $(\operatorname{Maps}(X,\mathbb Z_2), +)$ are isomorphic groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of $\Delta$ as follows:

> $A\Delta B$ is the set of things that are in *exactly one* of $A$ and $B$

things flow rather nicely.  Associativity and commutativity are immediate, and once you identify the identity and complement, they are straightforward too.

Comment: Associativity is immediate? It is perhaps the hardest part of the proof, though it certainly is not very hard in itself

Comment: $A\Delta B$ is the set of things that are in exactly one of $A$ and $B$.  Therefore $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ is the set of things that are in exactly one of $(A\Delta B)$ and $C$.  Such an element is either in exactly one of $A$ and $B$, and not $C$, or is in $C$ and either none or both of $A$ and $B$.  Thus $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ is the set of things in an odd number of members of $\{A,B,C\}$.  This argument is obviously symmetrical, so $A\Delta  (B\Delta C)$ must be equal to $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$, as required.

Comment: Almost immediate.